# Etymology of angle shooting in poker?

Tags: etymology

> **angle shooting**.
> Intentionally using an angle to exploit an opponent such as obscuring the size of their chip stack or acting out of turn. […].
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_poker_terms)

Another definition…

> [Angle shooting is] various underhanded, unfair methods to take advantage of inexperienced opponents. The difference between an "angle shooter" and a "cheater" is only a matter of degree. What a cheat or thief does is patently against the rules; what an angle shooter does may be marginally legal, but it's neither ethical nor gentlemanly. Nor is it in the spirit of the game.
> — [pokernews.com](https://www.pokernews.com/pokerterms/angle-shooting.htm)

What is etymology and earliest occurrence of this phrase? I have googled this but nothing obvious so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origin of the expression appears to be from the game of pool from which, by extension,  was used in other sports and games indicating a tricky move:

> ***[angle](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/nf2n3li)*** n.:
>
> [? the calculation of angles necessary to play a winning game of pool, snooker or billiards]
>
> 1. (orig. US) any plan that should benefit its maker, an exploitable gimmick, an ulterior motive; thus get an angle on v., to work out the optimum way of doing something.

The earliest quote they give is from 2003, but there are probably earlier exemples;

> 2003      B. Mulholland in Card Player Mag. I 7:3  *The game is eight-or-better stud. Player A, who’s a notorious angle shooter, has a split pair of kings (one up, one down) on fifth street.*

(Green’s Dictionary of Slang)